# how can I give client limited permissions to azure file storage?

Tags: file, azure, storage

using windows azure blob storage and providing access via a url with a Shared Access Signature is going great to upload files from local drive from client side. but how can I do the same with azure file storage to give a client access to it?

Answer (score 1):

Azure File storage service is not designed to provide external users access to files. It's primary purpose is to act as a file share for cloud services and virtual machines running in Azure.

You should use Azure Blob storage and Shared Access Signatures to share files with external users.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, `Shared Access Signature` is not supported for `Azure File Service`.

One option I could think of is read the file contents in your application and have your application download the file (using something like content-disposition).

Comment: Shared Access Signature is now supported for Azure File Service.